# Connect to netty with a client which does not use the netty framework

Tags: java, android, frameworks, netty

I use the netty framework to build a async nio server. Now i want to connect from an android app to this server. But im not able to use netty wit an android application, because there are to many functions which are not supportet by the android JVM. I there a way to connect to a netty server using SSL/TSL android socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly no reason why an arbitrary client should not be able to speak to a netty-based server, so long as both parties implement the same protocol.

e.g. OpenSSL s_client can talk to a netty-based SSL server.

So, implement your Android code following the myriad of SSL/TLS tutorials for blocking IO, if you find that easiest, and they should be able to talk to your server easily enough.

Comment: Ok do they need the same certificats? If yes, how can i get the netty certificat?
Is this a good idea to use the netty framework with a none netty client, or do you have some better solutions for me?
Problem is, i can connect from Android app with a netty based solutions to my server but cant send any message . . . So i want to use a pure Android solution and build an SSL Client with blocking I/O. Netty has to much methods which are not supported by android.